# Disable Enterprise mode / Emulate different version of Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, emulation

Can anyone guide me how to disable enterprise mode of Internet Explorer using Html code for e.g. meta tag?

Or

How can I emulate different version like IE8/IE9 etc using HTML meta tag ?

I tried something like below, but its not helping.

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
```

Comment: Why are you not manually changing the mode in the browser console or ever better use virtual machine images from Microsoft with the actual browser.

Comment: @epascarello : I want few of my software features to run properly on my client's machine. I cannot ask client to turn off enterprise mode. Is there way anyone know?